# Cálculo Digito de control código de barras

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación que me permita calcular el dígito de control del código de barras, pero utilizando la librería Tkinter de python.

EL algoritmo que calcula el dígito es:

```
EAN = "123456789041"

def eanCheck(ean):
    checksum = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(ean)):
        checksum += int(digit) * 3 if (i % 2 == 0) else int(digit)

    return (10 - (checksum % 10)) % 10

print "Digito de control: %d" %eanCheck(EAN)
```

Me gustaría que me indicaran cómo adaptarlo a una interfaz gráfica básica en Tkinter mediante la que se introduzcan números en una ventana y al pulsar un botón calcule el dígito automáticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes una sencilla implementación. He comentado el código para que pueda servirte para aprender y para que lo extiendas como necesites.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, StringVar, END, W, E

class EANCalculator:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Barcode")

        # Variables con la entrada del usuario (ean) y la salida producida
        self.ean = ""
        self.digito_control = ""

        # La salida la mostraremos en una Label (cuyo valor podremos cambiar)
        self.texto_digito_control = StringVar()
        self.texto_digito_control.set("")
        self.digito_control_label = Label(master, textvariable=self.texto_digito_control)

        # Delante de la cual pondremos otra Label con texto prefijado
        self.label = Label(master, text="Digito de control:")

        # Registramos un validador de modo que cada vez que el usuario escriba un
        # nuevo dígito, el validador será ejecutado. Lo usaremos para permitir
        # que sólo pueda introducir dígitos y no otros símbolos
        vcmd = master.register(self.validate)
        self.entry = Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))

        # Un par de botones. Uno para calcular y mostrar el dígito de control
        # el otro para borrar la caja de entrada de texto
        self.boton = Button(master, text="OK", command=self.update_digito_control)
        self.boton_borrar = Button(master, text="Borrar", command=self.borrar)

        # Los elementos anteriores no son visibles hasta que no los pongamos en un "layout"
        # En este caso uso como layout un grid con tres filas y 2 columnas
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.digito_control_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)  # La entrada ocupa 2 columnas
        self.boton_borrar.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.boton.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def validate(self, new_text):
        # Esta función verifica que lo que el usuario va introduciendo es un entero válido
        # Es llamada cada que vez que se pulsa una nueva tecla en la caja de entrada, o cuando
        # la entrada es borrada
        if not new_text:   # Si no hay texto nuevo, es que se ha borrado
            self.ean = ""  # Reiniciar la variable interna y dar la entrada por buena
            return True
        try:
            int(new_text)  # Mirar si se puede interpretar como entero
        except:
            return False   # No admitirlo de no ser así
        # Admitirlo (guardarlo y retornar True)
        self.ean = new_text

        # Si descomentas la línea siguiente, el dígito de control se actualizará a medida
        # que el usuario va introduciendo el código de barras. En este caso el botón OK
        # sería supérfluo
        # self.update_digito_control()
        return True

    def borrar(self):
        # Borrar la entrada y las variables asociadas
        self.texto_digito_control.set("")
        self.ean = ""
        self.entry.delete(0, END)

    def update_digito_control(self):
        # Calcular un nuevo dígito de control y mostrarlo en el elemento adecuado del GUI
        self.texto_digito_control.set(str(self.eanCheck(self.ean)))

    def eanCheck(self, ean):
        # Esta es la función que dabas en la pregunta
        checksum = 0
        for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(ean)):
            checksum += int(digit) * 3 if (i % 2 == 0) else int(digit)
        return (10 - (checksum % 10)) % 10

# Arrancar el bucle principal de eventos
root = Tk()
my_gui = EANCalculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Ejemplo en ejecución:

[image: Pantalla]